# How to display the product details when clicked from the list of products

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to build a backbone.js app with Ruby on Rails on the server side.

I am able to get the list of products and that looks great.

Next task is to display the product details when a user clicks on the product. As per my code when I click on a product I then get an alert message "**/products/20.json**".

Question: Do I need to manually make an ajax call using jQuery or should backbone.js help me get the value for this product given that Backbone.js is REST compliant?

```
$(function(){

  window.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { name: 'name missing' },
    urlRoot: '/product'
  });

  window.ProductList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product,
    url: '/products.json'
  });

  window.ProductViewForListing = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.template = $('#productTmplForListing').template(),
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    className: 'product',
    render: function(){
      var fragment = $.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
      $(this.el).html(fragment);
      return this;
    }
  });

  window.ProductViewForShow = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#main'),
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      self.el.append($('Hello world'));
    }
  });

  window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#products'),
    events: {
      "click .product": "showProduct"
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      var self = this;
      this.collection.each(function(product){
        var view = new ProductViewForListing({model: product});
        self.el.append(view.render().el);
      });
    },
    showProduct: function(e){
                   console.log(e);
      var href = $(e.target).closest('.product').find('a').attr('href');
      alert(href);
    }
  });

  var products = new ProductList();
  products.fetch({
    success: function() {
      new AppView({ collection: products });
    }
  });

});




<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="productTmplForListing">
  <a href="/products/${id}.json">
    <img alt="${name}" class="productImage" height="190" src="/system/pictures/${id}/thumbnail/${picture_file_name}" width="190" />
    </a>
    <p class="productName">
      <a href="/products/${id}.json">
        ${name}
      </a>
    </p>
    <p class="productPrice">
      ${price}
    </p>
  </script>
```

Comment: you can and it is recommended that you paste your code here on SO.

Comment: I pasted the code in the question itself. However I do not like the fact that for SO does not make use of full width of the browser and instantly puts the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Understandable, but the reasoning behind having code on here is to have a consolidated question and answer that can stand alone.

Comment: makes sense. without the code question will not have any value tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your `products` Collection, after calling `fetch`, should have an array of fully formed Product Models, assuming that your rails products controllers index action looks something like:

```
def index
  products = Product.all
  render :json => products
end
```

In other words, the Product model that you pass to your `ProductViewListing` is already fully in memory. It just so happens that you're only accessing the `id` attribute in your template.

In short the answer to your question is no, you don't need to manually make an ajax call, because you already have all of the models' info in your Products collection.

Comment: Do you have a backbone.js question radar monitor? You are on a roll buddy ;)

Comment: @Nupul I'm learning my way around Backbone, and I'm finding that answering these questions is a good way to consolidate my understanding. :)

Comment: Agreed. Helps me immensely too :)

Comment: I know in this case I do not need to do a server round trip. However assuming that on collection I am not collecting all the attributes of the model then I will have to . How would I do that? Also how calling the show on model works with backbone.js router. As you can see my app does not have any routes yet. Any tips on how to get that started.

Comment: Models also have a fetch method: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch. You can use that to get all the details of your individual model instances.